# How to select the key of a group order by column a where a column b is not ordering

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, postgresql-9.2

is it possible to select the id of the groups ordered accending by column line_to where a column obj_id is not also ordered accending?

So the result for my test-data should be 200 because line_no 2 with obj_id 25 is followed by line_no 3 with obj_id 12. And 300 because line_no 1 with obj_id 11 is followed by line_no 2 with obj_id 10.

Database is PostgreSQL 9.2

Thanks in advance

```
DROP TABLE data;

CREATE TABLE data (id int NOT NULL, line_no int NOT NULL, obj_id int, PRIMARY KEY (id, line_no));

INSERT INTO data VALUES 
  (100, 1, 11),
  (100, 2, 12),
  (100, 3, 15), 
  (100, 4, 18), 
  (200, 1, 11),
  (200, 2, 25),
  (200, 3, 12), 
  (200, 4, 18),
  (300, 1, 11),
  (300, 2, 10),
  (300, 3, 12), 
  (300, 4, 18),
  (400, 1, 11),
  (400, 2, 23),
  (400, 3, 35), 
  (400, 4, 38);

SELECT id FROM data GROUP BY id;  -- must be extended, the result should be 200 and 300
```

Comment: post the result table from above i/p table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some simple SQL will do the trick.

`SELECT DISTINCT d1.id FROM data d1, data d2 WHERE d2.id = d1.id AND d2.line_no > d1.line_no and d2.obj_id < d1.obj_id`

Comment: I thought it was a complicated problem, so I was blind for such simple solution. Thank you very much for your quick answere.